# C# getting array index from console navigation

Tags: c#, chess

I have this subroutine (below) that lets me navigate this 2d array printed to the console with the arrow keys, is it possible (if so, how?) to get the index of the item hovered over when the enter key is pressed? I can add the rest of the code if needs be.

```
    public static void BoardMobility(string[,] ChessBoard, Board board)
    {
        Console.CursorLeft = 1;
        Console.CursorTop = 0;
        bool exit = false;
        int vertical = 0;
        int horizontal = 0;
        do
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo choice = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (choice.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow && vertical > 0)
            {
                Console.CursorTop = vertical;
                vertical--;
                Console.CursorTop = vertical;
            }
            else if (choice.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow && vertical < 7)
            {
                Console.CursorTop = vertical;
                vertical++;
                Console.CursorTop = vertical;
            }
            else if (choice.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow && horizontal < 21)
            {
                if (horizontal == 0)
                {
                    Console.CursorLeft = horizontal;
                    horizontal = horizontal + 4;
                    Console.CursorLeft = horizontal;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.CursorLeft = horizontal;
                    horizontal = horizontal + 3;
                    Console.CursorLeft = horizontal;
                }
            }
            else if (choice.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow && horizontal > 2)
            {
                Console.CursorLeft = horizontal;
                horizontal = horizontal - 3;
                Console.CursorLeft = horizontal;
            }
            else if (choice.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                // this is where i would like to "collect" the index of the item hovered over
            }
        } while (!exit);
    }
```

Comment: You printed the board, right?...  This means you know at row and column it starts, along with where a "row" and "column" is positioned. Do some simple reverse math to figure out where the cursor is.  Alternatively, you could MAINTAIN that information in an "Index" and/or "X" and "Y" variables and update those values as you move around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to get the index of the item hovered over when the Enter key is pressed. You can calculate the index using the current vertical and horizontal positions of the cursor.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
else if (choice.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
{
    int index = (vertical * 8) + (horizontal - ((horizontal + 1) / 4));

    // Now you can use the index to access the corresponding element in the 2D array
    Console.WriteLine("Selected element: " + ChessBoard[vertical, index]);
}
```

In the code above, index is calculated based on the current vertical and horizontal positions of the cursor. The formula calculates the index of the selected element as if the 2D array was flattened into a 1D array (note that we subtract one from the horizontal position divided by 4 because there are 3 spaces between each column).

After calculating the index, you can use it to access the corresponding element in the 2D array (in this case, ChessBoard[vertical, index]) and do whatever you need with it.

I hope this helps!